# Fetching a drive file image using Urlfetch App in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I found a new way to access a dive image using the file ID. The image file is public shared for testing

https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1wJsovhXjWZM5qfyh3_VvJKODxw1DWQG_=w320-h200-k-iv1

This url would produce 302 and then render a browser image perfectly.

But When I run using a URLFetch it gives me error **400. That’s an error.
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.**

I have tried with

```
function myFunction() {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1wJsovhXjWZM5qfyh3_VvJKODxw1DWQG_=w320-h200-k-iv1", {
        'followRedirects': true,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        }
    })
    DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob())
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation is this new way documented or is this a hack you think should work?

Comment: It's a hack to fetch the file. When the link is placed in IMG tag it works great

Comment: And you do understand these links are not static they can and do change.

Comment: Yes I know, they do change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two things

1. If you fetch a publicly accessible URL, you **do not** need to authenticate.  Just remove the following line:

```js
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        }
```

2. If you try to fetch the redirection URL `https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1wJsovhXjWZM5qfyh3_VvJKODxw1DWQG_=w320-h200-k-iv1"`, you will get the following as result:

[image]

If you want to get the actual image instead, you need to fetch the actual URL of the image:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fife/ABSRlIr3o6GAAI3eXS8cz1Z9bWEkLp-D6RhKP8NDUfH81qWSIVA9Jj2XYE5XRifQ1-PZAPKEeH9t-0eqPCY6u_mD87pZ_hsTM9atsTL6rpDW5uZQgWVXH-UHuEMZspXRnYeZdZ87r9KQ4_YeO7z55p7qBnJeerzOaP3K_qhbEjCGpx2Eb5ln6gpvgaxAdUdV5HhUtw5d821iiod8JFNWqfiq7uGK0mvLKqUl7ZKIskhYBYW7G7r1uz5H-7DAymiwFQtQ6d2dUrWRWmms0u7O7Q5TSJHXt2HxhibEpgsFxBAK17GAmOTUa3bii3VoGifUXlKlGU1QAKH_i5ttFZn_Bbak2RzivY6QC1uDG-LgirWMzTT-2zqZcIM115qSDzrfktDaryHxBhIrUVvhrlWJ5j3QaRfUHh3__HSDgkm_Xe7-QCD3PuEYOgjxAsaLQoD3tdCywfKBWAT0crHJtTFQxtWmwR5RwNeLbFrzoeCEvVhZcaaYupC6Hwrtz8WHExAMnDHojXhqXCAwNSVYVzFVnxiigbZvl6UbSqXYsBqm_DLYlftCZ7pr28pkCnn_gKkbqitzIb-ei0mnOPFjqmMCAstLTTh4H7buZrAVvZZeYRe8xl9ypkAal_0z81L7dx3qVzCtFn6JuCRSZnlIFVseDURpFL4vDB6jqXoaEmwXt-ajA9MxefprFo6ujAdjFr_sUzHboBCfz9r3hPhvO21Qb2R2rnKGEpDRUuXr7Q=w320-h200-k-ft", {
    'followRedirects': true,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  })
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob().setName("blob from url"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64606635/get-the-lh3-googleusercontent-com-link-of-every-slide-via-google-apps-script here is another question.

Comment: The question is how to get the redirect long url from short url

Comment: The "long" URL is a `thumbnailLink` to the image. You can obtain it e.g. with [Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) setting `fields` to `thumbnailLink`.