# Get the lh3.googleusercontent.com link of every slide via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I have seen some of the Slide addons that bring every Slides for offline processing (as GIF/Video etc)

There are links that render as image for every slide in this slide file

lh3.googleusercontent.com

Like for example for the slide https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1FkU_qsca09I_jEmu95uGemBQT6U0kmkULUNrPoVp9OA/edit#slide=id.gc6f8954bc_0_164 has for each of the slides so the addon uses to create a GIF from a Client JS Library fetching

```
    https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZUpAW8v5h_NTjp9bZra4KELW90te9EM7R-P8EOacIHc0LL_tK-K6ZEOs2Q4s8nTdqIF-lzet4_Fcf_6IlZ9t8ZI23-_to9_0deGSiSzlCpqA9YS-wWdhEQyhPr0sz8yB3-YCZgWLHPy1t3_cU7cgGEvI0-hQKQ0TKG2eiF9ENNThj2uMt1UGe7IRhQb6x4F0pHL-WDNqkGgwrkfXNnXIdvYLzZ7pTMrmno159TPo1Q=s1600
    https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/dosqELnuNKVuYR54MeO3uEZ4dA2Icx5WV-y6cOpRJRMVchpido76366RE6WrZDsXMzyqrNKvfxnHrCAMlqWLwEBwgEMWqzheqFzwQDYop9JAEr3bkHd84KXQiBQSYfamlOYQ0UpIORR2n8IxL8SSvkCnYcpeyXnz-M2j9kr7I1O7qSYaCccyoeQCTwGrlVErwdFYIkbmU84tPZwlSNGCpXtAPEfWri7lsoyre_BImQ=s1600
    https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/EMsFOKDtH_21H76500Ef49bfRj6dr2oco4VMqeDDdK8J9YA0xOIrKUl_KPIvIBOT4vbQ-r_Bid9W6R2AiKgkNFib9gRp59zLvxPweNFVoqODrjx7dze_OmhXXdHaErp0UdwGEuynO8rFcvlUxRT8DZM4sOBZcqwk0sFisA6J6lGZwjH4b7KcyiOiGNP36BrpKm1u4fmGgj1k5uwRqyyQ4tSej1VyjYyt9bV_hsZS_A=s1600
    https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/P6rQrOUlpvePCSEoc8kp0aIQW7i-L4yrsNxv9CCtlrht0-cY9tswKAwFZxCG8ZkhvY6nK2zLx65PaNvE3gntt9G_4IJH6gZyhoCyJBNlQtpTPKAt7Z7cYI5Gm5wfcwrjbmnIIENiSqtA6oarxa9SfbRxs8707cBFbRa89I5gYxTdS-i_Ki48unlwrjTxhqsKtV2ki9KkjmF1WicF47WQQ9RbS9mw8cuyD-IpcR5aZA=s1600
    https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/GpHXmcG0FGpXMiufxnben0B9mVKuQeFkX7Vj9MASJb33xhhIOUGbEusoebDWPCDqnvsHxlQsoM90VP_oZF-ts0MKv9C9c1K-qqkY_XBrFukel-1LaCymrV4dbyoFK9lGIRqBEn7mtDE_MYuBH-YXvV-MnQoeM0JTjVMB61LFDGUbM2gX5n1cJKVWJEGL3QFf7iz7KH5U_eWK5iwCgmeGd0MjUz7uj0JrRHAbUMhrQg=s1600
    https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FyOudFxNPy9UPfklotm4Ua9fYkCO2_VcBMR3F5d29aEt6QVKryhPO-KTtut4fuM4dTqWsN1VH79nE4sqfnN_o6IHJuo-eG5f196QEFNpRshMzKswgtWldOk1V-me3NDWFqyZnpSLj8WJ4tda-0UQTirevJVwlku9sDufKFchPzFf1JGuHU2Mw51I8tVyHHDJJs3teECNfj9RHKAe32GR91j1nGSWZLx1dDFwVhtR5A=s1600
    https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/OrvHRPJ3hpp6Gfg9uHaVCOw2lMFQD_Ttb5GsA-bjYnPCuHPgBm4-03e7P6gYLw8BFGAPHwx4LWQxGSIprKWSV-mcKT-i_tihNMBlpWivV-YnkVs5z0ZczE8nwOaL8fsyGKPPXp89os2COactVl80wveOlVrQ5xxCOKPwqrQ2Bssub_kusJEWCakLTXFQ6SGzm56BeZP7oHvb4cD-_2BVjRJ35wRL0kWGQSiLOKA6Wg=s1600
    https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/w4jKkHzPp5OubkM9iaU8Z1ILyimMweJL1pLzXHPe29wYeIAYZfIKz2HJm8LLNdXf7Vj80PmYXo8HJ_pSteKH7UpL7cB_DrVNOZ-9LLOVt-RTM2akcjDZJ0YET7htXjdn720OciSaR2l8l3ILXA1HEXD5xGjzJDXKVI5WR0VVwmdXwlAkrTMQ4-EZJXjHZb7f99sV7UtawMnpyFBVGRGOA3NELkZXZv1QsSGfx0SGwg=s1600
    https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/cJNxxncyyL1sFm5o73i9atLMcMkgRPZPDKpeePnxUmP-VuAFXCMC-VxXZW788PhCx8LoySD9nEqNgY0Oc9lHTyiMGgIz4kpX9pgQZHcfZJrlJC73AL-Hw3BuXCmGKg3uggnZE5hqSxJVYaGVwpjDdBbw7h1t6Rf7JWke--wzRtFnshBN4old7tSdOXGjKCXd3ogs0vm0F6I5iyxO0twY4O3j9aAFkK9FGnehv_VAkw=s1600
    https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/Gf66EndRCb3sIix5wYVLF_5Qe6aB4y2AlvhuWtjR3QdGZxiCnHjo88SrS32Qd-O5t60MwNb69iURpUJU9z1E4Az88MqLj6dZF4-StAyeAM3kkWmnEF_JWNMnvrZ52OXueefAZsjis0pcD8CtFOPEavE2GX3O8XkMYNgVyt8PwqKV1Mj7iEAHsv13Z6qt41uxTD2eIl377Jmtp9j6Muvdy3NF9rm4W1ZMTTJL4-6rjQ=s1600
```

Could anyone explain how to fetch the lh3.googleusercontent.com URL of every slide files.

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution of your this question?